# Expect Script for SFTP not working in bash

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, sftp, expect

I have created a shell script containing an expect script for getting a file from remote location. Everything works well, until some command is sent. Whether it is 'ls' or 'pwd' or any other command, the expect script ends abruptly. Could you guy help me out with this.

NOTE : Security is not a concern, hence not using Public keys.

```
#!/bin/ksh

FTPREMOTEPATH=/Inbox
FTPREMOTEFILENAME=test.CSV


/usr/bin/expect -f - <<EOFEXPECT1
set timeout 60
spawn sftp -oPort=1002 username@test.server.com
expect {
        default { exit 1}
        -re "failed|invalid password|Permission denied" {exit 2}
        "Connection closed" {exit 1}
        timeout {exit 1}
}

expect "Password:"
send "password\r"

expect {
        default {exit 1}
        -re "password|Enter password for " {puts "Incorrect Password"; exit 2}
        "sftp>" {send "cd $FTPREMOTEPATH \r"}
}

expect "sftp>"
send "pwd\r"

send "get $FTPREMOTEFILENAME \r";

EOFEXPECT1
```

In above script, the scripts end abruptly after sending cd $FTPREMOTEPATH.

Below is the Output :

```
$ ./test.sh
spawn sftp -oPort=1002 username@test.server.com
Enter password for username
Password:
sftp> cd /Inbox
sftp> $
```

Comment: If you want to see more output you need to add more `expect` lines. Often a script is just send...expect...send...expect.  At the end use `expect eof` to wait for the connection to close (if you sent a command that should close the connection).

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Apparently i was missing **expect "sftp>" {send "bye\n"}** , before EOF (EOFEXPECT1).

However, i would still be interested in knowing the significance of bye in expect script.

Here is the updated and working code :

```
#!/bin/ksh

FTPREMOTEPATH=/Inbox
FTPREMOTEFILENAME=test.CSV


/usr/bin/expect -f - <<EOFEXPECT1
set timeout 60
spawn sftp -oPort=1002 username@test.server.com
expect {
        default { exit 1}
        -re "failed|invalid password|Permission denied" {exit 2}
        "Connection closed" {exit 1}
        timeout {exit 1}
}

expect "Password:"
send "password\r"

expect {
        default {exit 1}
        -re "password|Enter password for " {puts "Incorrect Password"; exit 2}
        "sftp>" {send "cd $FTPREMOTEPATH \r"}
}

expect "sftp>"
send "pwd\r"

send "get $FTPREMOTEFILENAME \r";

expect "sftp>" {send "bye\n"}

EOFEXPECT1
```

Comment: The last line in the script, after you send `bye`, should be `expect eof`

Comment: @glennjackman - The "eof" can be omitted because no action is required (ie. a simple "expect" (without eof) will suffice).

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you call a local restaurant, and say "get me some food" and then just hang up. What is the restaurant supposed to do?

When you wait for the sftp prompt, you're waiting for the food to be delivered.

I'd recommend 2 things:

1. before `send "get ...` change the timeout value to `-1` -- that will help if it takes longer than 60 seconds to receive the file.
2. after you send "bye", `expect eof` -- that lets the sftp connection close gracefully.

Comment: Thank you @glenn  , this helped me to get an insight. Does it mean that, once told expect to GET the file, it has nothing to do, so it stops and kills the SFTP ? And hence a 'bye' statement is necessary ?

Comment: if `get` is the last line in the script, you instruct sftp to begin the download, but then the script ends. When the script ends, the spawned sftp process is killed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your Expect script has reached the end of the script, and therefore terminates the child (ftp) process before the ftp process has a chance to finish downloading the file.

[image]